# Service Fabric - Distribute Memory Cache

Tags: azure-service-fabric, memorycache

Is it possible to distribute memory cache across nodes in Service Fabric?

I'm currently using memory cache to store a logged in users authentication ticket, but when I deploy to an environment with multiple nodes this stops working ...

Let me know if you require code samples.

Comment: How about using a stateful service?

Comment: And how will that help?

Comment: Well, think about it: state is kept in memory and is replicated across nodes. A ready made implementation can be found here for example: https://github.com/SoCreate/service-fabric-distributed-cache

Comment: Is there no way this can be achieve with stateless app?

Comment: I suppose you can run redis cache in a container on azure or something like that.

Comment: Also, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1#recommendations